# Whats correct "an quiz icon" or "a quiz icon"?

Tags: grammar

I'm always struggling to understand the rule behind "a" and "an". Can someone point me to a general rule or explain me when to use what?

How do I correctly write about an icon is it "an quiz icon" or "a quiz icon"?

Comment: This is one of the simplest and least contradicted rules of English.  You use "a" if the immediately following *sound* is a consonant, "an" if the immediately following *sound* is a vowel.

Comment: It is "an icon" if there is no word between the article and "icon" because "icon" starts with a vowel but when you have "quiz" between them it's "a quiz icon" because "quiz" starts with a consonant. If you had "attractive" after the article it would be "an" giving you "an attractive quiz icon" because "attractive" starts with a vowel. The only awkward ones are some words starting with "h" which often have "an" in front of them. For instance it is quite common to say "an hotel"  because the "h" isn't really sounded in "hotel"